# In Jmeter how to make the jmeter fail a test based on the medium response time?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

test plan screenshot:

[image: test plan screenshot]

For example instead of using 2000 as a threshold for each sample when do the assertion, I want to assert based on the medium response time. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using the easiest solution already. Implementing assertion on average response time is possible, but a little bit tricky as you will need to use a [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) which will:

1. Store response time for each request into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
2. On each request completion calculate [arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean) of all existing JMeter Variables and compare the result to the expected value.

The easier way would be running your JMeter test via [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool. Taurus can execute existing JMeter tests providing some extra reporting and other features, particularly for your use case [Pass/Fail Criteria Subsystem](http://gettaurus.org/docs/PassFail/) seems to be the perfect match